# Como configurar o IIS para o seu correto funcionamento?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis

Quando executo minha API pelo Visual Studio CTRL + F5 ou F5 e abro meu aplicativo que consome essa API ele funciona perfeitamente (Ambos em mesma rede ou através do redirecionamento de porta do NAT).

Entretanto quando publico, dou o publishing, a API funciona em apenas um dispositivo conectado por vez. Quando faço uma requisição pelo navegador ou o aplicativo desktop o aplicativo android fica em espera, a mesma situação quando pausamos a API, não lança timeout, entretanto quando saio de umas das aplicações, encerro o processo da requisição, a outra realiza a requisição perfeitamente (**este cenário não ocorre quando está sendo executado pelo Visual Studio**). Tentei algumas configurações e já verifiquei a versão do .NET está tudo ok.

O código abaixo é o web config da aplicação.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
   <aqui vem minha conection>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <remove name="WebDAV"/>
      <!--<add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="*" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />-->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.2.0" newVersion="1.2.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <!-- <providers> <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />  </providers> -->
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 6F0F52CF-412D-4F33-80C9-6A2C9B66B17E-->
```

O código abaixo é o config do ASP.NET.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
        <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
        <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
        <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>

    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>
```

A porta que está sendo executado é a 8058.

Comment: Não acho que o problema tenha a ver com o IIS. Existe algum código condicional pra debug, ou seja, que só execute no Visual Studio? Ou o código fonte é o mesmo para a versão de publicação e a de desenvolvimento? A base de dados acessada pelo Visual Studio e pelo ISS é a mesma?

Comment: Sim a base de dados e o código são os mesmos por isso achei estranho esse comportamento, em alguns artigos o pessoal disse que nessas situações pode ser a versão do .NET, mas está tudo ok.

Comment: Quando a aplicação fica em modo de espera, ela tem alguma transação em andamento?

Comment: Ela faz a requisição, mas retorna normalmente, tem o signal que está conectado, a aplicação é um chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou desacoplar da sua máquina utilizando outra máquina como servidor para testar ?
Pois tive um problema semelhante e quando publiquei em outra máquina como servidor, funcionou corretamente .... Infelizmente ainda não consegui descobrir qual era o problema na minha máquina mas aparentemente é alguma configuração no meu IIS

Comment: Coloquei o IIS em outra máquina e realmente solucionou, provavelmente era alguma configuração do meu IIS , estava realizando os pré-testes antes de lançar para produção, agora vai!